# Exchange 2010 / Outlook inbox search returning no results

Tags: exchange-2010

I moved our two Exchange 2010 DB's from spanned drives to their own individual drives last night - we have two, one at 200GB and the other at 350GB. I also moved the Message Queue DB and Transaction logs to their own 20GB dedicated drive. All went swimmingly until I came into work this morning and some users are unable to search their mail from within Outlook. The message is 'no matches found' - myself included but not one of my colleagues.

Investigation started with Event Viewer and I found a few Event ID 102's:

```
Exchange Search Indexer has failed to crawl the mailbox (babb50fd-3bb0-4dc3-b952-2257884c7e9c) in database (Mailbox Database I) due to error: (Microsoft.Exchange.Search.MailboxCrawlFailedException: Failed to logon to mailbox). This mailbox will be retried later.
```

I've run the `ResetSearchIndex.ps1 -force -all` script and Event Viewer is telling me it's started to create a new search index and enabled the index on both databases.

However nothing has changed in the past 2 and a half hours and I'm led to believe the process shouldn't take that long to complete. Is there something else I could look at? I'm no Exchange admin but I can follow instruction.

We're not using cached mode as we're a terminal server environment, Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2010 SP2 fully patched.

Comment: Do you see any more information in the Application log? Is the AD working as it should? (I'm thinking replication wise)

Comment: Yep, all good from that side of things. Ran the BPA tool a couple of times and issues reported. I also ran Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus and the ContentIndex State is still 'crawling'. I think I'm being a little impatient to be honest.

Comment: Well, you should see SOME sort of progress soon. Is the DB part of a DAG?